# Armadillo - Norm of each small block in a long vector

Tags: c++, armadillo, rcpparmadillo

I am using Armadillo in C++.

I have a long vector with 10 elements. I want to take norm 2 of each block of 2 adjacent values. In the end I will have 5 values.

In R I can convert that vector into a matrix and use apply but I am not sure how to do it in Armadillo. Appreciate any help

Comment: the [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) has relevant functions: [reshape()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#reshape), [norm()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#norm), [submatrix views](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a matrix from your vector and then loop through the columns.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]


// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec foo_Cpp(arma::vec x) {
// Note that the dimension of x must be divisible by two.
  arma::mat X = arma::mat(x.memptr(), 2, x.n_elem/2);
  arma::uword n = X.n_cols;
  arma::vec norms = arma::vec(n);
  for (arma::uword i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    norms(i) = arma::norm(X.col(i), 2);
  }
  return norms;
}



/*** R
foo_R <- function(x) {
  X <- matrix(x, 2, length(x)/2)
  apply(X, 2, norm, type = "2")
}
x <- rnorm(1000)
all.equal(foo_R(x), c(foo_Cpp(x)))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(foo_R(x), foo_Cpp(x))
*/

> all.equal(foo_R(x), c(foo_Cpp(x)))
[1] TRUE

> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(foo_R(x), foo_Cpp(x))
Unit: microseconds
       expr       min       lq        mean     median        uq       max neval
   foo_R(x) 17907.290 19640.24 21548.06789 20386.5815 21212.609 50780.584   100
 foo_Cpp(x)     5.133     6.34    26.48266    19.4705    21.734  1191.124   100
```